# I'm not able to reconnect to WiFi automatically after interruption in the router when using ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, freertos

Here is my code to connect to a WiFi network using EPS8266. I connected a DHT sensor to ESP. I'm able to get data when there is no interruption if interruption occurs at the router I'm not getting sensor data and also I'm not able to reconnect to the WiFi network

```c
static void wifi_task(void * pvParameters) {
    uint8_t status = 0;
    uint8_t retries = 30;
    struct sdk_station_config config = {
        .ssid = "CloveIOT",
        .password = "CloveIOT",
    };
    printf("WiFi: connecting to WiFi\n\r");
    sdk_wifi_set_opmode(STATION_MODE);
    sdk_wifi_station_set_config( & config);
    while (1) {
        while ((status != STATION_GOT_IP) && (retries)) {
            status = sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status();
            printf("%s: status = %d\n\r", __func__, status);
            if (status == STATION_WRONG_PASSWORD) {
                printf("WiFi: wrong password\n\r");
                break;
            } else if (status == STATION_NO_AP_FOUND) {
                printf("WiFi: AP not found\n\r");
                break;
            } else if (status == STATION_CONNECT_FAIL) {
                printf("WiFi: connection failed\r\n");
                break;
            }
            vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            --retries;
        }
        if (status == STATION_GOT_IP) {
            printf("WiFi: Connected\n\r");
            xSemaphoreGive(wifi_alive);
            taskYIELD();
        }

        while ((status = sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status()) == STATION_GOT_IP) {
            xSemaphoreGive(wifi_alive);
            taskYIELD();
        }
        printf("WiFi: disconnected\n\r");
        sdk_wifi_station_disconnect();
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, now I am using this WiFi connection method which works well.
**Before using `delay(1200);` it did not work and stalled on `WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED`.**

```
void connectWiFi() {
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(1200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println(F("connectWiFi"));
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(F("."));
  }

  Serial.println(F(""));
  Serial.print(F("Connected to "));
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print(F("IP address: "));
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
```